# How do you pass data into word VBA through a web application?

Tags: vba, winapi, ms-word, pywin32, python-docx

My goal is to create a web application that populates a word document to download or save.

Here is the website that I am working on:

https://cullerwhale.github.io/tinypets/1single.html

Here is an example of the website and the existing output:

[image]

Here is an example of the desired output:

[image]

I want all of it to be completed through the website. So passing the output (image of animal and label such as "great pyrenees") through the web API, into a VBA script somehow, and having the ability to download or save the populated document.

I am open to using VBA, python's win32 , python's docx library, or any other suggestions.

Thank you!

Comment: The Office Add-ins platform seems to be what you're looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins

Comment: Passing data from a web-app to VBA is not a particularly good idea security wise. There are javascript libraries that can generate docx files.